# Accessing instance variables from another class from a static method

Tags: java, instance, static-methods

I have the following code:

```
    public static boolean isRelated(Animal first, Animal second){
    boolean result=false;
    if(first(parentA).equals(second(parentA)))
        result=true;

    return result;
}
```

basically, I need to be able to access the parent A instance variable that is in the Animal class from this static method.

I understand that, to access instance variables in a static method, you need to create an object but I already have 2 brought in.(Parent A and Parent B)

Could  you guys tell me what the problem here is?

Comment: Do you mean `first.parentA`? You should review a basic java tutorial on classes and objects.

Comment: lol sorry, I did that initially but was messing about afterwards but anyways that doesn't work either.

Comment: Don't _mess about_. Learn the syntax and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access instance variable, you need to use an instance. You don't have to create it each time you need it, as long as you have one.

And for your code:

```
if(first.getParentA().equals(second.getParentA()))
```

In this case you need to make sure than `first.getParentA()` isn't `null` before comparing (or else you'll get NPE)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(first(parentA).equals(second(parentA)))
```

> > basically, I need to be able to access the parent A instance variable that is in the Animal class from this static method.

That is not the correct syntax to access instance members

should be

```
 if(first.parentA.equals(second.parentA))
```

More over use setters and getters to access the data such that

```
public class Animal  {
    private String parentA;

 //  code

  public String getParentA() {
    return parentA;
  }

  public void setParentA(String parentA) {
    this.parentA = parentA;
  } 
}

}
```

Then use the line `if(first.getParentA().equals(second.getParentA()))`

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are created in method area, and is the first to be created. Instance variables are created in heap after static methods are created. Hence, accessing instance variables directly is not possible. Always make use of an object to access such variables.